# C# application developed in monomac & xcode not executing on windows with mono framework

Tags: c#, xcode, windows, mono

I have developed a simple application with a window having a button in Mac using xamarine studio and xcode. I have compiled and created HelloMonoMac.exe

I have installed mono framework on windows machine and opened mono command prompt

```
mono HelloMonoMac.exe
```

It gives the following error

```
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception
 was thrown by the type initializer for MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector ---> 

System.DllNotFoundException: /usr/lib/libobjc.dylib
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector:GetHandle (string)
  at MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at HelloMonoMac.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication ---> System.TypeIn
itializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /usr/lib/libobjc.dylib
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector:GetHandle (string)
  at MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Selector..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at HelloMonoMac.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have also copied MonoMac.dll in the same folder where .exe was.

Is it possible to develop some application in mono with xcode and run it on windows?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, check this:
[mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/dllnotfoundexception/)

Comment: This is the problem in linux/mac. But I have it in windows, hope you can help me with some web resource similar to this.